# The Weil height on a generic fiber of family of abelian variety

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, heights

In the paper [Canonical heights on varieties with morphisms](http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1993__89_2_163_0.pdf) by Joseph H. Silverman, in page 184 (which is page 23 in the PDF) Silverman uses Lang's Fundamentals of Diophantine Geometry to show that
$$|h_{{V,\eta}_V}(Q_V)-\deg Q^\ast\eta|\leq c$$
[image]

Where $V$ is a generic fiber of the family $\pi: T\to \mathcal{V}$ is a family of abelian varieties as defined in page 177, section 3 (page 16 in the PDF).

The given reference is:

[image]

Which is an equality and not an inequality as in the first image. My question is where did the constant in the inequality $|h_{{V,\eta}_V}(Q_V)-\deg Q^\ast\eta|\leq c$ came from.
My guess is that we can think on $\eta_V$ as a formal sum of hyper surfaces in $\Bbb{P}^n$, and since the Weil height has the property: $h_{D+E} = h_D + h_E + O(1)$, that is why the constant $c$ appears.

I'm a bit confused.

Thank in advance.